# I try but I don't understand how build CSS from SCSS in VSCODE

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code

All is in the title :)

How can I build css from sass file in vscode ?
In task file I just found lines for LESS not for SASS...

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Use Easy Sass: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=spook.easysass

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.

My root path has a /css folder underneath with my styles.scss file & the associated map file. I also had to fix my path for ruby. Once those two were working, my build showed an error where ruby couldn't find the scss file. So I fixed my task file - here is the working file. Notice the ${fileDirname} - that fixed the build errors for pathing.

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "sass",
    "args": ["${fileDirname}/styles.scss", "${fileDirname}/styles.css", "--trace"],
    "isShellCommand": true
    }
}
```

But this was just a test -- it doesn't watch and build more than 1 file as you would normally want to in a larger system. The docs for gulp/automation are here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/CSS

Answer (score 0):

We don't have predefined problem matchers for SASS yet. You might want to open a feature request here https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/List

But you can always create a problem matcher for SASS yourself. Have a look at the doc here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/tasks#_defining-a-problem-matcher